# redirect to previous page on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Below is my design and code where I am trying to redirect to previous page on button click which doesnt work.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_back" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/go_back.jpg"  OnClientClick="Back()"   Height="41px" Width="49px" />


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style_demo.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style5 {
        height: 33px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function Back() {
       debugger;
        history.go(-2);
        return false;
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
```

Comment: did you try `window.history.back()` or `window.history.go(-1)`

Comment: i tried this but doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
history.back();
```

Comment: I have set debugger on javascript, but the javascript Back() on clientclick is not called as it doesn't take me to debugger

Answer (score 0):

If your desired page is always your last page you navigate from, you can go back.

```
window.history.back();
```